# Swift - table is empty after moving between controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm updating existing Objective-C app.

There is a structure:
AppDelegate
- creates mainBackgroundView and adding subview with UITabBarController

I have in one "Tab" HistoryViewController:

```
@objc class HistoryViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let historyTableViewController = HistoryTableViewController()        
    self.view.addSubview(historyTableViewController.view)
  }

}
```

And HistoryTableViewController:

```
import UIKit

@objc class HistoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// Mark: properties

var historyCalls = [HistoryItem]()

// Mark: private methods
private func loadSimpleHistory() {
    let hist1 = HistoryItem(personName: "Test", bottomLine: "text", date: "10:47")
    let hist2 = HistoryItem(personName: "Test 2", bottomLine: "text", date: "10:47")
    let hist3 = HistoryItem(personName: "Test 3", bottomLine: "text", date: "10:47")
            historyCalls += [hist1, hist2, hist3]
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.loadSimpleHistory()

    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HistoryCallTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HistoryCallTableViewCell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return historyCalls.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HistoryCallTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? HistoryCallTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Coulnd't parse table cell!")
    }

    let historyItem = historyCalls[indexPath.row]

    cell.personName.text = historyItem.personName
    cell.bottomLine.text = historyItem.bottomLine
    cell.date.text = historyItem.date


    return cell
}

}
```

When I open the navigation tab with HistoryViewController for the first time, table appers with data. When I click into the table or switch navTab and then go back, table is not there anymore.

When I switch to another app and then go back, table is there again.

How to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Reload table view to the view will appear

Comment: and how to do it please?

Comment: check `adarshu` answer if not then let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call data method in viewwillappear and reload the table..

```
  override func viewWillAppear() {
     super.viewWillAppear()
     self.loadSimpleHistory()
     self.tableview.reloadData()
  }
```

Comment: I just needed to put it into HistoryTableViewController and form HistoryViewController viewWillAppear call htvc.viewWillAppear - the viewWillAppear in UITableView is not called automatically